# Explain ggplot2 warning: "Removed k rows containing missing values"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get this warning when I am trying to generate a plot with `ggplot`.

After researching online for a while many suggested that my database contains either null values or missing data in general, which was not the case.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549463/the-meaning-of-warning-message-removed-4-rows-containing-missing-values-geom-p) the accepted answer says the following:

> The warning means that some elements are removed because they fall out of the specified range

I was wondering what exactly does this range refer to and how can someone manually increase this range in order to avoid all warnings?

Comment: There is a limit on the `y` axis on that question. Values are limited between 0 and 0.12 because of this function: `ylim(0,0.12)`

Comment: A reproducible example would help answer the question. @LyzandeR seems to be going down the right track.

Comment: ...also I have noticed that even just adding "jitter" to a geom_point() plot can occasionally throw an unexpected data point out of range and get give this error.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is due to how `ggplot2` deals with data that are outside the axis ranges of the plot. `scale_y_continuous` (or, equivalently, `ylim`) excludes values outside the plot area when calculating statistics, summaries, or regression lines. `coord_cartesian` includes all values in these calculations, regardless of whether they are visible in the plot area. Here are some examples:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Set one point to a large hp value
d = mtcars
d$hp[d$hp==max(d$hp)] = 1000
```

All points are visible in this plot:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(mpg, hp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  labs(title="All points are visible; no warnings")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

In the plot below, one point with hp = 1000 is outside the y-axis range of the plot. Because we used `scale_y_continuous` to set the y-axis range, this point is not included in any other statistics or summary measures calculated by ggplot, such as the linear regression line calculated by `geom_smooth`. `ggplot` also provides warnings about the excluded point.

```r
ggplot(d, aes(mpg, hp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,300)) +  # Change this to limits=c(0,1000) and the warning disappears
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  labs(title="scale_y_continuous: excluded point is not used for regression line")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

In the plot below, the point with hp = 1000 is still outside the y-axis range of the plot. However, because we used `coord_cartesian`, this point is nevertheless included in any statistics or summary measures that ggplot calculates, such as the linear regression line.

If you compare this and the previous plot, you can see that the linear regression line in the second plot has a much steeper slope and wider confidence bands, because the point with hp=1000 is included when calculating the regression line, even though it's not visible in the plot.

```r
ggplot(d, aes(mpg, hp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,300)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  labs(title="coord_cartesian: excluded point is still used for regression line")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Answer (score 23):

Just for the shake of completing the answer given by eipi10.

I was facing the same problem, without using `scale_y_continuous` nor `coord_cartesian`.

The conflict was coming from the x axis, where I defined `limits = c(1, 30)`. It seems such limits do not provide enough space if you want to "dodge" your bars, so R still throws the error

> Removed 8 rows containing missing values (geom_bar)

Adjusting the limits of the x axis to `limits = c(0, 31)` solved the problem.

In conclusion, even if you are not putting limits to your y axis, check out your x axis' behavior to ensure you have enough space

Comment: This is so often missed. By the same person. Again after some time... *sigh* Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I know this question already has an answer, but this is another possible solution for you. As you don't provide a sample code, I couldn't know for sure.

If you just want to get rid of it, that implies to me that you are OK with the output. Then you can try the following:

- Add `na.rm=TRUE` to `geom_something` like : `geom_line(..., na.rm=TRUE )`

This explicitly tells geom_line (and geom_path) that is OK to remove NA values.

##### Analyzing the warning message:

> Warning of: Removed k rows containing missing values (geom_path)

This tells you mainly 3 things:

- geom_path is being called by another geom_something which is firing the warning.
- It already removed k rows. So if the output is as desired, then *you want* those rows removed.
- The reason for removal is that some values ARE missing (NA).

What the warning doesn't tells you is WHY those rows have missing (NA) values, that only you may know.

An usual reason comes from setting limits to the scale. Like `scale_x_datetime` or `scale_y_continuous`.

This makes sense as (X,Y) pairs, to be drawn, requires not to be NA.

When you set the X scale to larger values where there is no Y, OR your Y data is NA. You get (X,Y) points where one of both is NA.

You may want to set a larger scale for a different number of reasons, but ggplot will always find that there isn't an associated Y value, and it makes sense to fire a warning instead of an error.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

### Another important variation on this for ***Histograms*** developed in 2019.

The computation was updated and includes something - excuse me for maybe oversimplifying -
like creating bins according to the `limit=()` specification on your binning axis,
and if this is wider than your data,

- it creates bars with 0 frequency
- it creates this same warning for those bars

**– a completely different problem than clipping your data but with the same message.**

The ggplot developers suggested in github handling this a few different ways,
https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3265
https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4083

#### 1a. If using `limit=()` inside an axis declaration, set your `limit=()` precisely to the range of your bars, even if your axis breaks are wider

#### or 1b. Add option `oob = scales::oob_keep` to the offending axis declaration

#### or 2. If using `xlim` or `ylim`, wrap it in `coord_cartesian()`

Comment: Option 1b should be `scales::oob_keep`. 
Example: 
` + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 300), oob = scales::oob_keep)`

Comment: good call -- addressed in source but then I copied in the wrong one

Answer (score 1):

Even if your data falls within your specified limits (e.g. `c(0, 335)`), adding a `geom_jitter()` statement could push some points outside those limits, producing the same error message.

```r
library(ggplot2)

range(mtcars$hp)
#> [1]  52 335

# No jitter -- no error message
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,335))


# Jitter is too large -- this generates the error message
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(w = 0.2, h = 0.2)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,335))
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, but in the case where I wanted to avoid the extra error messages while keeping the range provided. An option is also to subset the data prior to setting the range, so that the range can be kept however you like without triggering warnings.

```
library(ggplot2)

range(mtcars$hp)
#> [1]  52 335

# Setting limits with scale_y_continous (or ylim) and subsetting accordingly
## avoid warning messages about removing data
ggplot(data= subset(mtcars, hp<=300 & hp >= 100), aes(mpg, hp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(100,300))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for that, is existence of NA's. Suppose your array name is `arr`. You can simply check if you have any NA's in your array by:

```
any(is.na(arr))
```

If the answer was TRUE, then you have to delete NA's as below:

```
arr = arr[-which(is.na(arr)]
```

Even without `any(is.na(arr))`, you can simply run the above command and R will remove any NA's that might have existed.