# "prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading" in geom_smooth()

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I plot my data using `ggplot2` and get the error `"prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading"`. See here:

```
# Data.
temp <- structure(list(x = c(-62135599651, -62135599057, -62135598463,  -62135597869, -62135597275, -62135596681, -62135596087, -62135595493,  -62135594899, -62135594305), y = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5,  0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
# Plot.
ggplot(temp, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method= "lm")
```

The `geom_smooth()` line in the plot looks wrong (as the error suggests):

[image: Plot]

There is a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429055/warming-rank-deficient-and-missing-values) but it lacks a reproducible example and has no answer. What can I do here?

**Edit**

For those who want to further see how to solve it statistically see my question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567831/relationship-of-covariance-and-linear-regression-in-context-of-rank-deficiency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're encountering a numerical precision rounding problem.

You could center `x` by substracting `mean(x)`.

```
ggplot(temp, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method= "lm", formula = y ~ I(x-mean(x)))
```

[image]