# Removed 20 rows containing missing values (geom_segment)?

Tags: ggplot2, na, geom

I don't know why it is giving the waring message of Removed 20 rows containing missing values (`geom_segment`). I have checked for NA's using `sum(is.na(BS_cell_228))` and answer is 0 and maxium data point is 72 on y-axis.

I tried `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 80))` but nothing has changed.

Would highly appriciate any suggestions.

Here is my code

```
plot3 <- plot2+scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,70,10))
plot3+expand_limits(y=0)
```

Comment: Can you share your data with `dput()`?

Comment: Thank you, Vinicius. Could you please let me know what information you would want to have from dput(). It is big, even if I run for only one row, it exceeds the word limit here to post. Is there any other way I can share it with you?

Comment: You can create a subset with a few rows and only the columns you use in your code so I can reproduce here

Comment: > dput(BS_cell_210[1:4, ])
structure(list(Line = c("210-9-10_Null", "210-9-10_Null", "210-9-10_Null", 
"210-9-10_Null"), BS_Cell_length = c(43.240048, 43.685188, 48.732605, 
32.699542), BS_Cell_width = c(20.808799, 21.285797, 19.44217, 
18.527763)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

Comment: Thank you very much, @Vinícius Félix, for trying to help me.

Comment: Have you looked here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505298/explain-ggplot2-warning-removed-k-rows-containing-missing-values You may be getting this error due to `NA`s, `NULL`s, or `Inf`s; we can't know without seeing all your data.