# Detecting removed rows in ggplot2 warning: "Removed k rows containing missing values"

Tags: r, ggplot2

Referencing these past two questions:

[Explain ggplot2 warning: "Removed k rows containing missing values"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505298/explain-ggplot2-warning-removed-k-rows-containing-missing-values)

[The meaning of Warning message: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_path)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549463/the-meaning-of-warning-message-removed-4-rows-containing-missing-values-geom-p)

Given that I have a ggplot with the warning "Removed k rows containing missing values"

How do I detect the removed rows in order to assess the reasons for removal / if the rows are impactful in the analysis?

Answer (score 0):

To detect the rows that were removed by ggplot2 **due to missing values**, you can first use the `na.omit()` function to remove all rows with missing values from your dataset before creating the plot. 
Afterwards you can compare the original dataset to the one with the missing values removed to see which rows were removed and assess whether or not they are impactful to your analysis. 
To compare the original dataset to the one with missing values removed, you can use the `setdiff()` function from the base R package. This function will return the rows that are present in one dataset but not the other. [Documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/prob/versions/1.0-1/topics/setdiff)
For example, if you have a dataset called df and you create a new dataset called df_clean using the `na.omit()` function, you can use `setdiff()` like this to find the rows that were removed:

```
df_clean<- na.omit(df) 
setdiff(df, df_clean )
```

Comment: The dataset is huge there are surely missing values that are not relevant to the ggplot command.